# Kibana query exact match of entire value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

I have a series of records with a field `App Version` that currently has two possible values: `2.3.0` and `2.3.0 SP1`. If I try to do a query for just `2.3.0` in the Dev Console like so...

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "App Version": "2.3.0"
      }
  }
}
```

It returns all records, both ones with `2.3.0 SP1` **and** ones with `2.3.0`. Since my ultimate goal is to delete all records with just `App Version=2.3.0`, I need some way to filter out the ones that include `SP1`. I can't find documentation anywhere that forces an exact match of the *entire string*, rather than just part of the string. Any ideas?

**Edit**: I'm running Kibana 5.2.2 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the exact match you should use a term query on a non-analyzed field (ES 2.X) or on keyword field (ES 5.X). But I suppose you will have to change the mapping.

I alternative you can combine two or more queries in a [`bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "App Version": "2.3.0"
            }
          }
       ],
       "must_not": [
          {
            "match": {
              "App Version": "SP1"
            }
          }
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this query **doesn't** guarantee to return only records which have   app version: `2.3.0` rather returns all records which matches `2.3.0` and doesn't contain `SP1` . i.e in case if you get new value for app_version e.g `2.3.0 SP2` then this record will also get matched. Hope OP understand this caveat.

Comment: Using `"App Version.keyword": "2.3.0"` for the match query is exactly what I needed. It only matched `2.3.0` and not `2.3.0SP1` or `2.3.0 SP1`. The exclusion logic will be incredibly useful for an ELK newbie like me, though, so thanks!